# removeChild so I can load new FLV_Player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, removechild

I am making a flv player with playlist that has and English and Spanish section. The English is the default section and that works very well but when I click "Spanish" button I am trying to remove all the children that were added at start time and run two new functions that load my Spanish data.

The only thing is that removeChild is not working. I can hear my Spanish video load but the English one is still playing in the background.

I need to completely remove `main_container.addChild (my_player);`

here is the function that should do it all:

```
function playSpanish (evt:MouseEvent){
    main_container.removeChild(my_player);
    gotoAndStop(2);
    trace("IN SPANISH");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have stopped your player:

```
my_player.stop();
```

If you want to remove all children from main_container, you could:

```
while(main_container.numChildren > 0)
{
    main_container.removeChildAt(0);
}
```

Comment: the english video continues to play but I can hear the spanish one start too. Not sure why its not being removed.

Comment: Assure appropriate life cycle:  "my_player" instance must first: stop(), remove children, add children and apply settings for next language.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is a little late in getting to you, but it'll be useful to future readers. This problem has been the bane of many of my projects. Here is the solution:

```
my_container.removeChild(my_flvplayer_instance);

my_flvplayer_instance.getVideoPlayer(0).close();

my_flvplayer_instance=null;
```

the key is `getVideoPlayer(0).close();` which closes the netstream hidden within the FLVPlayback component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using net stream you need to close the connection to the stream, how are you implementing this player?

Answer (score 0):

Removing a display object(my_player) from the stage does NOT stop its functions from working. You just will not see it
This is why garbage collection fails and creates memory leaks.
You need to to do the follow.

```
function playSpanish (evt:MouseEvent){
    // make sure you call stop on the video to you know it is not playing
    my_player.stop()

    // remove it from the container/stage
    main_container.removeChild(my_player);

    // remove all event listeners
    my_player.removeEventlistener( EVENT, funcName );

    // null the object out to help promote garbage collection
    my_player = null;


    // do your other code here
    gotoAndStop(2);
    trace("IN SPANISH");
}
```